# How to return a specific variable from PHP to Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have followed his popular tutorial to connect Android to MySQL:
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

It is great at encoding the data back in JSON and displaying rows of data.

My question:  What id I want to return just a single value, a single varaible from PHP to Java?

Here is my PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ratings WHERE item_id = 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
```

I want to send that last "echo" back to Android, on the guidelines of that tutorial above, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$row is an array and it should have a value like:

```
$row['AVG(rating)'] = <some value>
```

All you need to do is throw the `json_encode` function around row and echo it out

```
print(json_encode($row));
```

This should get you the single value json encoded string that the java code can read.

Comment: I don't understand that row would have to have some value?  The PHP code works as I typed it up.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array($result) will return a numeric array as well as an associative array, so $row[0] is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebView try `addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android")` http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html and call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showAndroidToast(avg_value) {
    Android.echo(avg_value);
  }
</script>
```